# Iterating through rows and columns of an Excel worksheet and getting the values

Tags: .net, asp.net, vb.net, excel

Is it possible to retrieve the value of a cell from the row and column index of an Excel.Worksheet? I need to itearate through all the rows and columns and get the values...

```
For row As Integer = 1 To worksheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    For col As Integer = 1 To worksheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count
      list.Add(worksheet.Cells(row, col)) 'this doesn't return the value of the cell
    Next
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
list.Add(worksheet.Cells(row, col).Value2)
```

Comment: @Prabhu: I know and you don't have to worry about this. Value2 is _hidden_ but you have to take that property to have a cell value. I don't remember if you have to cast it to your type...

Comment: @Marco...unfortunately, I get an error "Option Strict On disallows late binding" and I'm not sure I can turn it off.

Comment: This seems to work: worksheet.Range(worksheet.Cells(row, col), worksheet.Cells(row, col)).Value2.  Not sure if that's the best way though...

Comment: You could try using the `Value` property rather than the `Value2` property. There are only slight differences between them - see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff193553.aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
list.Add(worksheet.Cells(row, col).Value)
```